# $routeParams are undefined in on on destroy method

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do some cleanup before the scope change but i cannot access the `$routeParams` of the `scope` in the method.

Here is the method

```
mainAngular.controller('TableController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        console.log('I am calling leave, table '+ $routeParams.tableKey);
    });
}
```

This outputs

`I am calling leave, table undefined`

Why can not i access the `$routeParams` in this method?

Comment: $routeParams is available only in controllers configured with URL routing.

Comment: Try injecting `$route` and check if `$route.current.params` works, or save if before `var currParams; angular.copy(currParams, $routeParams);` and in the destroy event, check `currParams` instead

Comment: @Kalyan   I can access $routeParams in another part of the controller. I just can't access it inside the onDestroy method

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
mainAngular.controller('TableController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    var routeParams = $routeParams;
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        console.log('I am calling leave, table '+ routeParams.tableKey);
    });
}
```

Comment: This didn't work either. But if i assign the specific parameter to a variable then it works.
`var tableKey = $routeParams.tableKey`

Comment: Ok. you can try `var routeParams = angular.copy($routeParams);` if you want the whole object